# Is the Liénard equation the only ODE with bounded solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for ordinary differential equation with bounded solution. The only thing I could find is Liénard equation
$$x''(t)+f(x)x'(t)+g(x)=p(t)$$
there are some papers in the literature on the sufficient and necessary conditions for boundedness of Liénard equation but not for other equations.
Then it comes to my mind that whether Liénard equation is the only ODE with bounded solution?

Comment: Solutions of $x'' + \omega^2 x = 0$ have the form $x = a \cos(\omega t+c)$ and all of them are bounded...

Comment: solutions of $x’=0$ are constants and therefore bounded

Comment: Where does the right side $e^t$ come from? Do you mean bounded independent of initial condition? There are lots of first order systems that serve as examples for the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, apart from having a limit cycle most of the systems have solutions that are forward bounded. Note that even your equation with all qualifications is not backwards-bounded.

Comment: Autonomous equations $x'=f(x)$ have solutions bounded between the roots of $f$, consider for instance $x'=\sin(x)$.

Comment: generally on the right hand side that is p(t), a function of t. in the literature it is e^t to have a sufficient condition for bounded and periodic solutions.

Comment: x"+\omega^2 x=0 is a kind of Lienard eq.

Comment: That makes no sense. What is the real question with that, second order ODE $x''=F(t,x,x')$ that stay bounded despite the right side exponentially increasing in $t$ (with the other arguments fixed)?

Comment: x'=sin(x) is in the family of Lienard eq.

Comment: That can not be, it is not second order and it does not have an $e^t$ or even $p(t)$ term. // More seriously, I understand that for an equation $x''+c(x)x'+g(x)=0$ one usually demands that $c$ is non-negative and $G(x)$ coercive, with $G'=g$. That is, $G(x)\to+\infty$ for $|x|\to\infty$

Comment: the question is that is there a third order or higher eq with bounded solutions?

Comment: What do you mean with "3rd order"? If you mean anything that has an equivalent first order system of dimension 3, then I point you to the Lorenz system, that of the chaotic Lorenz attractor. It might be more difficult if the restriction is to scalar 3rd order equations, but they exist, one can easily construct linear DE with constant coefficients, there one only needs that all characteristic roots have negative real part.

Comment: I mean 3rd order ODE like y"'+y"+y'=0

Comment: As $(r+1)(r^2+r+1)=r^3+2r^2+2r+1$ has all roots with negative part, the solutions of $y'''+2y''+2y'+y=0$ are forwards-bounded, converging to zero.

Comment: thank you. yes that is true. Is Lienrad eq. the only eq in 2nd order with bounded solutions?